# Runtime Error: Slots is undefined after upgrading Vuetify to version 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3, vuejs-slots

I'm attempting to migrate my project to Vue3, and after upgrading Vuetify, I get a runtime error. Whenever I try to load my home page using `vue-cli-service serve` with the `@vue/compat` version, the screen displays the following error:

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR

slots is undefined
LoaderSlot@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/lib/composables/loader.mjs:35:7
```

I tried to render the home page of my Vue web app, which uses vuetify. I expected it to show my custom page, but it instead displayed an error message saying `slots is undefined`

Comment: It seems to be triggered by usage of a v-card component

Comment: @vue/compat is not compatible with vuetify, you have to use the full version of vue 3